# Memcached session driver PHP7.0 php.ini authentication

Tags: php, session, memcached

I am trying to use memcached as a session driver with PHP7.0. From what I understand from tutorials/blog posts is that you have to configure memcached as session driver in php.ini like this:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = tcp://10.1.1.1:11211
```

This seems to work, but my production memcached server works with sasl authentication. How do I pass the credentials for memcached in php.ini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of reading I discovered the following parameters:

```
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path="${MEMCACHIER_SERVERS}"

memcached.sess_binary=1 # for ext-memcached 2 / PHP 5
memcached.sess_binary_protocol=1 # for ext-memcached 3 / PHP 7

memcached.sess_sasl_username="${MEMCACHIER_USERNAME}"
memcached.sess_sasl_password="${MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD}"
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-sessions#storing-sessions-in-memcached

This has solved my question.